# Vorticity in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, vortex

Can you refer some good papers to read on quantum field vortices, and a comparison with classical field vortices?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Please elaborate on your question. The subject of vortex in quantum physics is quite broad. It's better to be specific.